# Unresolved plot lines in The Witcher

Tags: the-witcher

I recently completed The Witcher, and found myself wondering about some of the plot lines that didn't seem to be resolved.  I'm wondering if this is because of the choices I made (meaning they were addressed if I made different choices), or they were left to be addressed in The Witcher 2, or are they just meant to be open-ended?

Some examples I can think of

- What happened to Alvin after he teleported away from Murky Waters?  Is there a connection between his amulet and the one that the Grand Master of the Order of the Rose was wearing?
- Who was Triss talking to at the beginning of Chapter 3, and what was the relevance of their conversation?

Update: The Alvin situation is covered, anyone have more info about Triss's "secret" conversation?

Answer (score 8):

It's heavily implied that Alvin IS Jacques de Aldersberg, the Grand Master of the Order of the Rose. If you pay attention, Jacques will tell you all the stuff that you tell Alvin.

Some more info [here](http://witcher.wikia.com/wiki/Alvin).

Comment: Yes, that was my impression as well.  Triss even specifically mentions that Alvin could've teleported in time.  I was just surprised that it was left as only an implication.

Comment: Yeah, I missed it on my first playthrough too. It was only afterwards that I realized it.

Comment: It's more than implied. Alderberg makes active and direct references to conversations Geralt has had with Alvin. The game doesn't come out and say it outright, but it isn't exactly murky either.

Answer (score 6):

At the beginning of Chapter 3, Triss was talking to the sorceress Phillipa Eilhart through the magic mirror. Their conversation was pertaining to the Lodge of the Sorceress, a secret society whose head was Eilhart herself and the proceedings of the 'plan'. You'll get to know more about this once you play The Witcher 2.